# Retrieve geolocation and image url from Blob in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, geolocation

I have a web form that collects three items: name, notes, and a geotagged img and stores it in mysql. The image is stored as a blob.

I would like to scrape/access the blob's geo-location properties with a python framework (MySQLdb) and create a geojson.

I am familiar with connecting to the db and retrieving individual rows.

```
con = MySQLdb.connect(user=user, passwd=passwd, host=host, db=db)
cursor = con.cursor()
query = "SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table;"
cursor.execute(query)
```

Then start a cursor and save to text.

```
 for row in cursor.fetchall():
       ....
        print '{'
        print  '"id": "{0}",' .format(row[0])
        print  'name": "{0}",' .format(row[1])
        print  'notes": "{0}",' .format(row[2])
        print '"lat": "{0}",' .format(row[1])
        print '"long": "{0}",' .format(row[2])
        print '"url": "file://{0}"'.format(row[3]) 
        print '},'
```

What I'm interested in specifically is how to extract the geographic info and file url from the blob format?  Is there an easier method?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804768/interpreting-gps-info-of-exif-data-from-photo-in-python help?